# Помогите составить запрос к бд с django

Tags: django

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class StartTime(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='start_times')
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Нужно получить только самые первые актуальные времена с приоритетными событиями

```
queryset = StartTime.objects.filter(event__is_favorite=True, start_time__gt=datetime.now())
```

А теперь как получить только по одному времени на каждое событие, и при этом чтобы оно было самым ближайшим?

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Max
```

Определяем подзапрос в котором получаем время последней записи для эвента:

```
subquery = (
    StartTime
    .objects
    .filter(event=OuterRef('pk'))
    .order_by('-start_time')
    .values('start_time')[:1]
)
```

Далее аннотируем каждый `Event` полученным в подзапросе временем и фильтруем результаты по занчению поля `is_favorite`:

```
queryset = (
    Event
    .objects
    .annotate(latest=Subquery(subquery))
    .filter(is_favorite=True)
)
```

Вариант с [Max](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#max):

```
queryset = (
    Event
    .objects
    .annotate(latest=Max('start_times'))
    .filter(is_favorite=True)
)
```

Если необходим queryset содержащий объекты `StartTime` одним запросом не обойтись. Возможно воспользоваться вариантом с Subquery и в подзапросе получить `id` для последних `StartTime`:

```
subquery = (
    StartTime
    .objects
    .filter(event=OuterRef('pk'))
    .order_by('-start_time')
    .values('id')[:1]
)
```

Также аннотируем каждый `Event` полученным в подзапросе id, фильтруем результаты по значению поля `is_favorite`, а также убираем эвенты без связанных объектов `StartTime` и превращаем всё это в плоский список id:

```
ids = (
    Event
    .objects
    .annotate(latest=Subquery(subquery))
    .filter(is_favorite=True, latest__isnull=False)
    .values_list('latest', flat=True)
)
```

В итоге получаем объекты `StartTime`, соответствующие этим id:

```
queryset = StartTime.objects.filter(id__in=tuple(ids))
```

После решения [тикета](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28333) хорошим решением будет ранжирование объектов `StartTime` по полю `start_time` с помощью [Rank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#rank) и фильтр по рангу 1.

Comment: Возможно понадобится еще пошаманить с Queryset.query.group_by, но это крайние меры, а так все верно

Comment: Так получается, что queryser состоит из объектов Event, а мне нужен состоящий из объектов StartTime(дальше еще добавляются фильтры), как быть?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.